# css3 rounded chat bubbles with right 'arrow' and border

Tags: html, css, chat

I am struggling to create a chat pane with chat bubbles.

My HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="bubble">
```

Have a look at an example here:

[fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/qBSnb/)

My issue is that I somehow can't figure how to turn the second quote 'arrow' to the right.

Also, how can I add border so it can contain the 'arrows' as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/qBSnb/2/

Comment: @techfoobar for the right bubble, it'd probably be better to have the `::after` be a higher z-order than the `::before`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qBSnb/3/

Comment: @Shmiddty - Yes. In that fiddle `::after` has `z-index:0` and `::before` has `z-index:-1`

Answer (score 2):

Add these

```
 <div class="arrowright"></div>


  .arrowright 
  {
  background: #2C2C2C;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-left: -0.7em;
  }

  .arrowright::before {
  bottom: -0.666em;
  left: 0.8em;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1.2em solid #2C2C2C;
  border-top: 1.2em solid rgba(44, 44, 44, 0);
  border-bottom: 1.2em solid rgba(44, 44, 44, 0);
  content: "";
  }
```